# Question on integration

Tags: integration

Let $(p,q)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ , and $H: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

if $q'=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} (p,q) ~~\text{and}~~ p'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} (p,q)$

How to prove that $H(p(t),q(t))=1$

Please , help me

thank you

Comment: This is wrong. Let $H(p,q) = pq$, then your equation reads $q' = q$, $p' = p$, giving $p(t) = \exp(t)p(0)$, $q(t) = \exp(t)p(0)$, so $H(p(t), q(t)) = \exp(2t)p(0)q(0)$.

Comment: when i say p' , it means that  p'=dp/dt .

Comment: If I should guess what could be meant, I'd say you forgot a sign in from of either $\partial_p H$ or $\partial_q H$, and something like $H(p(0), q(0)) = 1$.

Comment: @martini ,yes i'm sorry i forget -

Comment: i edited ma question, can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

Under the condition that $H\bigl(p(0), q(0)\bigr)= 1$, we can argue as follows: Let $h(t) = H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)$ for all $t$. Differentiation using the chain rule gives
\begin{align*}
  h'(t) &= \partial_p H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)p'(t) + \partial_q H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)q'(t)\\
        &= -\partial_p H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)\partial_q H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr) + \partial_q H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)\partial_p H\bigl(p(t), q(t)\bigr)\\
        &= 0.
\end{align*}
So $h$ is constant, giving $h(t) = h(0) = H\bigl(p(0), q(0)\bigr) = 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Ok, and please if $H(p(t),q(t))=1$ how to see that $q'=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} (p,q) ~~\text{and}~~ p'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} (p,q)$ please, thank you

Comment: please help me thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou I do not understand your question, as in the OP, you are asking to prove sth follows from $q' = H_p$, $p' = -H_q$, now you are asking to show the convers, which wont hold in general ...

Comment: i see this we can't prove, the convers is false  ,thank you